# Transit Visa required in Brussels for Indian citizen

Tags: visas, transit, brussels

My flight from Montego bay(Jamaica) to delhi has connections in Brussels and Moscow. Airline gets changed at Brussels airport. I have one ticket only. Layover is for 3 hours. Would I need transit Visa?

Comment: @DJClayworth unfortunately it is very difficult to find information from the Belgian government about which countries' citizens require airport transit visas in Belgium.  The link to the same information from an official EU source in the duplicate question is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any official information in English, but on the Belgian immigration office's [Dutch-language page on airport transit visas](https://sif-gid.ibz.be/NL/deel_2.aspx), the absence of a mark in the box corresponding to India and Belgium indicates that Indian citizens currently do not require an airport transit visa in Belgium under any circumstances.